# I added tensor as backend then getting error like AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' has no attribute '_TensorLike'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have checked in `~/.keras$ vi keras.json tensorflow` as backend and also added `from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops` inside  `~/tensorflow/tensorflow/python$ vi __init__.py`

Comment: you question title is unclear :(

Comment: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' has no attribute '_TensorLike'